# Is there a good collection of examples of the different type of video cuts?

Tags: video, video-editor, tutorial

So I'm a beginner when it comes to video editing, but I hear and read about a lot of different types of cuts between clips, e.g. jump cut, smash cut, etc. I always felt it would be great to just see them demonstrated in some example video clip.

Have anyone seen such a resource, preferrably free, online, where most or all of these types of cuts are shown in examples?

Comment: I haven't found a resource where all the cuts are collected. But if you search youtube for `editing match cut` or `editing jump cut` you'll get plenty of examples. One could collect those and put it in an answer to answer the question.

Comment: As Bart said, if your looking for examples of these sort of cuts then yes check out youtube and take a look...my recommendation though would be to take a cheap class at say a community college on film/editing, you would probably learn a lot from such a class in terms of types of cuts and how to use them to tell a story.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia is not a bad resource for explaining the different types of edits in continuity editing. Some have examples using stills of the out and in points, or references to usage of the edit in a well known film sequence.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_editing

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/180-degree_rule

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/30-degree_rule

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_cut

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutaway_(filmmaking)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_on_action

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Establishing_shot

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyeline_match

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(filmmaking)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_cut

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_take

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Match_cut

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_reverse_shot

Answer (score -3):

Try to use Avidemux as free video cutting and joining software. Also try freemake video converter is quality software to convert multimedia files.

Comment: As I understand it the OP is more looking for examples of those cuts (to see the actual effect) rather than ways to actually generate that cut (with Avidemux). Hence the downvote.

Comment: That's correct. I have the tools to do the cuts, I just want a reference library of cuts being used in video editing in general.